# How to distinguish between silicone and nylon spatula and judge their quality

Tags: equipment, utensils

I bought a few silicon spatulas from [Amazon{The ones I bought}](https://www.amazon.in/Baskety-Stainless-Kitchen-Utensils-Silicone/dp/B07VMFGGHB).These are most probably from China, and since those are not from very well known brands, I can't just blindly trust what it says on the packaging. I don't want these to be the nylon ones.

How can I distinguish a nylon spatula from a silicon one.

How can I judge the quality/ safety of these spatulas ??

Comment: Do you have the link for the exact product you bought? It may say something there about what it says - part of my job is selling things on Amazon and you have to be very clear about what materials make up your product. Either the link or the ASIN would work to help us find your information.

Comment: @JCrosby https://www.amazon.in/Baskety-Stainless-Kitchen-Utensils-Silicone/dp/B07VMFGGHB This is what I have bought. It clearly states in the description that it's silicone, but I'm skeptical about how trustworthy it is. I'm afraid that they might actually be selling nylon spatula (because it's cheap) under the name of silicone spatulas

Comment: Price isn't always a good indicator. I have 4 silicone spatulas bought at a dollar store, and have used them almost daily for nearly 20 years. They've long outlived the more expensive, name brand silicone spatulas I've had.

Comment: It does say in the link you've provided: Product description
The secret to perfect cooking is right here!

Your search for the best kitchen utensil set is over

100% SATISFACTION GUARANTEE

-Ultimate combination of stainless steel handles along with silicone cooking heads to cook like a professional

Answer (score 2):

They look like nylon, but as you actually have them in your possession, the simplest test is to squeeze them. Silicone is soft & 'rubbery', nylon [or anything similar you can put in a pan] is hard & 'plasticky'.

Comment: The picture looks like nylon to me, but could also be a solid core with silicone layer.  Not as long lasting potentially and all silicone, but better at holding shape for things like the ladle and lifting.  There should at least be some surface give I would expect though.